# Make a C program that performs only three valid commands

Tags: c, string

The commands are case sensitive. The following are the commands:

1. ADD x,y; where x and y are literal integer values and ADD is all
   capital letters.  The ADD command do not display the result but
   merely performs addition on whatever values are there for x and y.
   The result of the operation is saved on a special variable called
   AX.
2. PRT AX - display the value of AX.
3. EXIT – Exits the program.

Your program should continue asking valid commands from the user until the user typed EXIT.

Example of valid inputs from the user:

- ADD 3,5
- ADD    4,   3
- PRT AX
- EXIT

Example of invalid inputs from the user:

- add 3,4
- ADD x,4
- ADD x,y
- DISPLAY AX
- PRT ax
- PRT y
- PRT 4
- Exit

I already tried making but unfortunately only made the ADD command. Can't seem to get the PRT AX command. Help me please :( Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char str[20];
char cmd[10], x[10], y[10], zip[32], set[32];
int AX, i, j;

int main (void) {

    while (str != 'EXIT') {
        scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", str);


        if (str != 'PRT') {
            calc();
        }

    }

return 0;
}

int add(int x, int y){
    return x + y;
}

int calc() {
    strcpy(cmd, strtok(str , " "));
    strcpy(x, strtok(NULL, ","));
    strcpy(y , strtok(NULL, ","));

    i = atoi(x);
    j = atoi(y);

    if ((strcmp (cmd, "ADD") == 0) && (strcmp (cmd, "add") < 0)) {
        AX = add(i,j);
       }

    return AX;
}

// i dont know what i did with this or what i did it for T.T 
void print() {
    strcpy(cmd, strtok(str , " "));
    strcpy(zip, strtok(NULL, " "));

    if (strcmp (cmd, "PRT") == 0 && strcmp (zip, "AX") == 0) {
        printf("%d\n", AX);
       }

}
```

Comment: You cannot compare strings using `!=` in C. Read up on `strcmp()`, and strings in general.

Comment: Or rather, you cannot simply guess the C language syntax, you actually have to know it. `str != 'EXIT'` makes no sense and will not compile. Please post the real code that actually compiles.

Comment: `scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", str);` will begin an infinite loop should only `"\n"` get entered.  Suggest `fgets()`.

Answer (score 0):

let em guess - you are seeing no output?

```
strcpy(zip, strtok(NULL, " "));

if (strcmp (cmd, "PRT") == 0 && strcmp (zip, "AX") == 0) {
    printf("%d\n", AX);
   }
```

What are you trying to achieve with `zip`?  You assign it to an empty string and then only print AX if it is equal to zip, which it will never be.

Note, you should have bracketed better (read up on operator precedence), so

```
strcpy(zip, strtok(NULL, " "));

if ((strcmp (cmd, "PRT") == 0) && (strcmp (zip, "AX") == 0)) {
    printf("%d\n", AX);
   }
```

But, really, you just need to forget zip and

```
void print() {
        printf("%d\n", AX);
}
```